# ASP.NET MVC Routing - Custom routes with blogs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a blog engine, and I need a custom route, like this:
localhost/blogname/posts/1
Where blogname should be handled by a BlogsController, and posts will be an action.
How would I define such a route?

Comment: You can try this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433504/asp-net-mvc-subdirectories/6433789#6433789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to define {controller} in your Url if you define it as a constraint. I think this should work:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Blogs", action = "Posts" },
    new { controller = "Blogs"});
```

It might cause problems with other routes though, I'm not sure. If it doesn't work, David's answer of http://site.com/blogs/posts/id is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a weird approach. If you use the default routing in ASP.NET MVC, you would need one controller class *per* blog--not something you can easily create on the fly.

If you use the classname `BlogsController`, then the default routing would work for URLs of the form:

```
/Blogs/SomeAction/123
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
public class BlogsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View(GetPostsOrSomething());
    }

    public ActionResult Posts(int id)
    {
        return View(new BlogViewModel(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(int id, string comment)
    {
        // do comment
    }
}
```

And your routing would need to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Blogs", // Route name
    "{blog}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Blogs", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

### Note

Bear in mind, this would match default style URLs, and everything might be routed to your `BlogsController`. Maybe you could consider a regular expression for the `{blog}` part of the pattern:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Blogs", // Route name
    "{blog}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Blogs", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { blog = "(blogname1|blogname2|blogname3|etc)" }
);
```

But, this isn't very flexible either. Any time you added a blog to your site, this regular expression would require an update. I would probably reconsider your URL structure--something similar to the default style.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Blogs", // Route name
  "{blogname}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Blog", action = "Posts", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

would work, meaning you could have your blog controller like this:

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Posts(string blogname, int id)
    {
        ... get posts based on blog name and id and return view...
    }

}
```

but then if you want a url like localhost/admin/dostuff/1 to go to an admin controller, how will MVC know that you don't just mean a 'blogname' called 'admin'?

You would need to do something like the regex matching that David suggests, or else specifically add a route for any other controllers you have before you add the Blog route

e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Admin Controller Routes", // Route name
  "admin/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Account Controller Routes", // Route name
  "account/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

... etc - one for each controller ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach to be best for my needs. Very simple, goal is to have the title of the blog as the parameter but also the URL (I didn't want a ? to set a parameter value, I have been told it is not helping SEO.   Goal is  *MYURL.com/blog/my-blog-title*

ASP.NET MVC
add to your RouteConfig.cs file

```
   routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Blog",
            url: "blog/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "GetBlog" },
            constraints: new { title = @"[\w\-]*" }
        );
```

Add a Controller and call it Blog and then add the following Action to that Controller

```
    [Route("blog/{title}")]
    public ActionResult GetBlog(string title)
    {
// do what ever code you need to do here to get the blog from the title and pass a model to the view using return View(MyBlogObject)
        return View();
    }
```